# How can to run custom action that would run on CANCEL/abort installation?

Tags: wix, custom-action, wixsharp

how can I run CA that would run on CANCEL/abort installation?

I'd like to run a command in case of cancel/abort.

I need it to support at quiet mode too.

Also, how can I detect it's on cancel mode?

Basically working with Wix# but Wix is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancelling an install causes it to rollback actions that were already executed. Therefore you want to set the `Execute` attribute on your `CustomAction` element to `rollback`.